# Trigger a build in Bamboo from a Jenkins job

Tags: rest, jenkins, bamboo

Currently all our Regression tests are configured in a Jenkins job.We want once the regression tests are completed,it should trigger a plan in our Bamboo server and also record the tests results in Bamboo using TestNG parser.Is it possible?

Ps : I have already seen Bamboo rest-api but can not seem to find a solution.Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Can I just ask why you're using Jenkins *and* Bamboo ?  It seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: We are in the process of transition from jenkins to Bamboo,and hence is necessary for us.@gareth_bowles

Comment: @stillLearning You should be able to do this using the Bamboo API, see docs here: https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo/REST/4.0/.

Comment: Yup i was able to do it.Thanks @TomHall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't been updated for a while and I'm not using it currently, thus can't confirm it is still working as desired (the download statistics suggest it being used though), but given there's not much to it, you should be able to achieve the first part of your use case with the [Bamboo Notifier](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bamboo+Notifier), which allows you to *Trigger a Bamboo build upon successful completion of a Jenkins job*.

The second part should be covered by the Bamboo [TestNG Parser task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/TestNG), though you'll need to push your existing test result files to Bamboo by some means of course, possibly by [Using the SCP task in Bamboo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Using+the+SCP+task+in+Bamboo).

Comment: Can you explain me more about how to use SCP?Do we have to configure a new SCP repo?